# Why does the electron lose energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We all know that when a photon impacts on an electron it delivers all its energy to the electron and the electron's energy increases and it goes to a higher-energy state -- meaning farther from the nucleus.  And it revolves there.  Now my question is: why does the electron lose its energy and come back to some lower-energy state?

Suggestions for books on QM are welcome.

Comment: I believe that the answer revolves around vacuum fluctuations, which turn the eigenstates of the pure atom not true energy eigenstates, therefore, not stationary.